# Nuclearity of test functions operating on a certain domain

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

we know of the nuclearity of  $D'(R^n)$ and  $S'(R^n)$ (distributions/tempered distributions) by using the isomorphy of  $D(R^n)$ and the space of rapidly decreasing sequences $s$ (which is nuclear) and the fact, that the dual of nuclear Fréchet-spaces are nuclear. 
Now I want to know, if the spaces  $D'(R^n\backslash \{0\})$ and  $S'(R^n\backslash \{0\})$ are also nuclear? I'm asking this because I want to apply the Nuclear Theorem (Gelfand-Maurin) to these spaces to get a full set of generalized eigenfunctions(or "eigendistributions") of a self-adjoint operator (for example a Hamilton-operator with a "Coulomb-like" potential, which at least secures the existence of a self-adjoint extension).